# Current and working instructions for generating PWAs for Windows 10, Android and iOS?

Tags: android, ios, windows-10, progressive-web-apps, pwabuilder

I'm trying to use Microsoft's PWA builder which seems to be a take over of manifoldJs of which the Microsoft documentation still exists for.  But it doesn't work at all.  It's like they've completely given up on this tool.

When you run the tool it looks for a non-existent image for windows10 splash screens that isn't referenced anywhere but looks on the site, and then fails to generate the windows10 content.  pwabuilder run android doesn't do anything at all. No error messages nothing.

One would think that if Microsoft is serious about this they'd have this working and be trivial. Heck, I should be able to go into the developer website and just point it at my PWA address and it should do the rest with nothing else involved!

Anyone have working steps anywhere? I can't find anything other than non-working docs from here: https://github.com/pwa-builder/PWABuilder-CLI

Comment: Did you find some new informations about pwabuilder?

Comment: Seems almost completely DOA.